# create custom nested output from json using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

```js
let data = {
  "needData": [
    {
      arrayData: [
        {
          "key": "dummy",
          "value": "needed value"
        },
        {
          "key": "secret",
          "random": "secret_random"
        },
        {
          "key": "another",
          "value": "testing"
        },
        {
          "key": "another_Secret",
          "random": "testing_value"
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
};
let json, testing;
data.needData.map((value) => {
  json = {
    arrayData: [
      {
        needed_key: value.arrayData[0].key,
        needed_value: value.arrayData[0].value,
      },
    ],
  };
  testing = {
    arrayData: [
      {
        needed_key: value.arrayData.key,
        needed_value: value.arrayData.value,
      },
    ],
  };
});
console.log("value got by running json", json);
console.log("value got by running testing", testing);
```

I am trying to save data in json object by using map function but the problem is I can save data by using `needed_key:value.arrayData.key` `needed_value:value.arrayData.value`

if all the needed_key and needed_value are same I can use above code but here problem is key name is same but the needed_value get change by `random and value` I only want to save values of those data which contain in `value` not `random` is there any way I can get `key and value` value not `key and random` value

I can use manual code to fetch the data but what if data is more and I don't want to use manual code

### Expected Output

```
{
  "arrayData": [
      {
          "needed_key": "dummy",
          "needed_value": "needed value"
      },
      {
          "needed_key": "another",
          "needed_value": "testing"
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: why is 4th record not expected

Comment: mistakenly I wrote value three time @cmgchess I was writing random in place of value copy past problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives your output:

```
var output = {
  'arrayData': data.needData[0].arrayData
    .filter(x => !Object.keys(x).includes('random'))
    .map(x => {
      return {needed_key: x['key'], needed_value: x['value']}
    })
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: i forgot the output format. this answer fulfills it

Answer (score 1):

`Array.map` and `Array.filter` implementation.

```js
let data = {
  "needData": [
    {
      arrayData: [
        { "key": "dummy", "value": "needed value" },
        { "key": "secret", "random": "secret_random" },
        { "key": "another", "value": "testing" },
        { "key": "another_Secret", "random": "testing_value" },
      ]
    }
  ]
};
const output = data.needData.map((value) => {
  const { arrayData } = value;
  const opArrayData = arrayData.filter(item => item.key && item.value && !item.random);
  const parsedArray = opArrayData.map((node => ({ needed_key: node.key, needed_value: node.value })));
  return { arrayData: parsedArray }
});
console.log(output);
```